# 違うFormにコンボボックスから得られた数値を渡す

Tags: vb.net, winforms

伺いたいことがあります（内容変更）。

ComboBox1のリストを選択しても、Form1からForm2に初期値の値しか渡りませんでした。

MessageBox.Show(idx)を実施したところ、数字に変化がありませんでした。

Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

この部分を1,2に変化させコンパイルすると、Form2で正しく動きました。ComboBox1のリストで選択した際に、idxも0～2に変化し、その結果、nsf値が1～3に変化させたいのですが、初期値の0のまま動きません。

どのようにすれば成功するかご知見を頂けますと有難く存じます。

①Form1

```
Public Class Form1

    Public nsf As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

        With Me.ComboBox1

            .Items.Add("1：A")
            .Items.Add("2：B")
            .Items.Add("3：C")

        End With

        Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

        Dim idx As Integer = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

        nsf = idx + 1

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim f2 As New Form2

        f2.nsf = Me.nsf

        f2.Show()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: そのコード正しいですか？ Form2 にあるボタンのクリックで Form2 を表示するのは変だと思うのですが。Form1 にあるボタンのクリックで Form2 を表示するのではないのですか？

Comment: ご指摘のとおり記載ミスでした。ボタンはForm1の下にありForm2は未記載です。新たに分かった問題として、 MessageBox.Show(idx)を実施したところ、数字に変化がありませんでした。

' 1番目の項目を選択する
        Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

この部分を1,2に変化させコンパイルすると、Form2で正しく動きました。
問題点が変わりましたが、ComboBox1のリストで選択した際に、idxも0～2に変化し、その結果、nsf値が1～3に変化させたいのですが、初期値の0のまま動きません。

Comment: 質問を編集して正しく書き直してください。

Comment: こんな記事やリンク集が参考になるかも。[別のフォームのデータを取得、設定する](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/form/accessanotherformdata.html), [\[VB.NET\] -参考リンク- サブフォーム、別クラスからメインフォームのコントロールを取得・設定する](https://www.invisible-works.com/archives/2020/09/post-3086/)

Comment: ちなみに更新された後の内容であっても、何が問題なのか・どうすれば状況が再現出来るか、といったことへの説明やソースコードが十分では無いように見えます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に、質問内容をブラッシュアップしてみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) あるいはもしかして本当にソースコードがこれだけならば、コンボボックスの値を変化させる操作を行った際に`nsf`変数の値を更新するイベント処理が無いからでは？

Comment: f2.nsf って何ですか？ 質問のコードはコンパイルも通らないのでは？

Comment: kunifさんのアドバイスをヒントに調べたところ、SelectedIndexChanged処理が抜けているのではと思い試したところ成功しました。nsf値も更新され、Form2で正しく計算が実行されました。また、参考リンク集でModule、shared処理も試したところ成功しました。comboboxは初めて使ったため、リストから選ぶと自動的に更新されると思っていたのが原因でした。お陰様で解決でき、様々な処理法を知ることも出来ました。

Comment: 解決したなら情報共有のために内容を自己回答してみてください。あと以前の質問のほとんどが未解決状態ですが、それらも解決したなら該当の回答を承認するか自己回答を、未解決なら質問に状況を追記・詳細化して助言・回答が得られる切っ掛けを増やすようにしてください。

Comment: 利用の初心者のため、承認する方法を知りませんでした。次のようにして解決できました。Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

            nsf = 1

        End If

        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

            nsf = 2

        End If

        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
      
            nsf = 3

        End If

    End Sub