# Visual Basic の出力ファイル処理について

Tags: vb.net

vs2019でvbコードを作成していましたが、自己解決出来なかったため投稿しました。

一番左列を計算ステップ数として出力し、同じ行に1点が3数値を持つ6カ所の計算結果を出力するものです。
6カ所のデーターのため、「NODE=6」としています。

「out.txt」に出力させると、下記のとおり1行目に1カ所分の3数値が記載された後に改行され、
6カ所分の数値が記載されてしまいます。

これを②のように、ステップ毎に1行に6カ所×3数値＝18を出力させる方法を知りたいです。
どのようにすれば1行毎に更新されて正しく数値を格納できるでしょうか。
コードを示しますのでアドバイス頂けますと有難く存じます。

①出力ファイル「out.txt」

```
 1,  0,  0,  0
 1,  1.63401841165215E-06, -4.23975684907087E-06, -2.44840995811576E-05
 1,  0,  0,  0
 1,  1.62765335623538E-06, -6.76145984583269E-06,  6.89722445866509E-07
 1,  0,  0,  0
 1,  1.6277681511652E-06, -2.60468852869766E-06,  7.00096162112573E-07

 2,  0,  0,  0
 2,  3.2680368232265E-06, -8.47951369814418E-06, -4.89681991621149E-05
 2,  0,  0,  0
 2,  3.25530671239303E-06, -1.35229196916688E-05,  1.3794448917347E-06
 2,  0,  0,  0
 2,  3.25553630225271E-06, -5.2093770573886E-06,  1.40019232422684E-06

 3,  0,  0,  0
 3, ･･･
```

②希望する出力ファイル形式

```
 1,  0,  0,  0,  1.63401841165215E-06, -4.23975684907087E-06, -2.44840995811576E-05,  0,  0,  0, ･･･
 2,  0,  0,  0,  3.2680368232265E-06, -8.47951369814418E-06, -4.89681991621149E-05,  0,  0,  0, ･･･
 3,  0,  0,  0, ･･･
```

③コード

```
    Dim LineW77 As New IO.StreamWriter("./out.txt", False, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))
    Dim aa77$

    'ステップ

    For Istp = 1 To Nstep

        '出力

        For J = 1 To NODE

            aa77$ = Str$(Istp) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J - 2, Istp)) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J - 1, Istp)) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J, Istp))

            LineW77.WriteLine(aa77$)

        Next J

        LineW77.WriteLine()

    Next Istp

    LineW77.Close()
```

Comment: タイトルは「～について」で切らずに、より具体的なものを心がけてください。

Comment: 出力するためのデータはどのように蓄えられているのか等、他の人が簡単に試したり調べたり出来るように、問題を再現させる最小限のソースコードとデータをすべて質問記事に提示して、追加の情報や回答しようとする人の推測等を必要とせず、１つの質問のなかで完結して確認出来るようにしてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: ちなみに説明やデータ等の無い`Nstep`や`Str$(D(3 * J - 2, Istp))`等の部分を適当な数値やダミーの文字列で置き換えて実行しても質問のような結果にはならないので、質問記事のソースコードには転記ミスや不足等により、そもそも不完全だと思われます。見直して正しく問題を再現するのに十分なソースコードとデータを提示してください。

Comment: 悪戦苦闘していましたが、次のようにして解決出来ました。

   For Istp = 1 To Nstep
        aa77$ = Str$(Istp) 
        '出力
        For J = 1 To NODE
            aa77$ = aa77$ + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J - 2, Istp)) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J - 1, Istp)) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J, Istp))
        Next J
        LineW77.WriteLine(aa77$)
    Next Istp

出力ファイル「out.txt」

 1,  0,  0,  0,  1.63401841165215E-06, -4.23975684907087E-06, -2.44840995811576E-05,  0,  0,  0,･･･
 2,  0,  0,  0,  3.2680368232265E-06, -8.47951369814418E-06, -4.89681991621149E-05,  0,  0,  0,･･･
 3,  0,  0,  0,  ･･･

Comment: こちらの質問 [違うFormにコンボボックスから得られた数値を渡す](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/94440/26370) などもそうですが、質問記事には正確で不足の無い情報を提示してください。そして自己解決したならコメントに書くのではなく自己回答してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

悪戦苦闘していましたが、次のようにして解決出来ました。

```
   For Istp = 1 To Nstep
        aa77$ = Str$(Istp) 
        '出力
        For J = 1 To NODE
            aa77$ = aa77$ + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J - 2, Istp)) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J - 1, Istp)) + ", " + Str$(D(3 * J, Istp))
        Next J
        LineW77.WriteLine(aa77$)
    Next Istp
```

出力ファイル「out.txt」

```
 1,  0,  0,  0,  1.63401841165215E-06, -4.23975684907087E-06, -2.44840995811576E-05,  0,  0,  0,･･･
 2,  0,  0,  0,  3.2680368232265E-06, -8.47951369814418E-06, -4.89681991621149E-05,  0,  0,  0,･･･
 3,  0,  0,  0,  ･･･
```